# Diplaying AVL Tree data in a GUI C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, avl-tree

Basically I have an AVL tree that stores instances of  Country class. When I do an inorder traversal of the tree, I am able to see the country details correctly, however I wish to view and modify instances of the country class in a GUI. The issue I am having is I have no idea how to access the class data and display it in something like a listbox. Here is my Country class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace International_Trading_Data
{
    class Country : IComparable
    {
        public string countryName { get; set; }
        public double gdp { get; set; }
        public double inflation { get; set; }
        public double tradeBalance { get; set; }
        public int hdiRanking { get; set; }
        public LinkedList<string> tradePartners { get; set; }
        public string f;

        public Country (){
    }
        public Country(string cname, double g, double i, double t, int h, LinkedList<string> tp)
        {
            this.countryName = cname;
            this.gdp = g;
            this.inflation = i;
            this.tradeBalance = t;
            this.hdiRanking = h;
            this.tradePartners = tp;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Country temp = (Country)obj;
            return countryName.CompareTo(temp.countryName);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            foreach (string i in tradePartners)
                f += i+",";
            return countryName+" "+gdp+" "+" "+inflation+" "+tradeBalance+" "+ hdiRanking+ " "+f;

        }
    }
}
`
```

This is where I create instances of the country class:

```
 public void loadFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        open.FilterIndex = 1;
        open.Multiselect = true;
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string selectedFilePath = open.FileName;
            const int MAX_SIZE = 5000;
            string[] allLines = new string[MAX_SIZE];

            allLines = File.ReadAllLines(selectedFilePath);
            foreach (string line in allLines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("Country"))
                {
                    headers = line.Split(',');
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                    LinkedList<string> tradePartners = new LinkedList<string>();
                    string[] partners = columns[5].Split('[', ']', ';');
                    foreach (string i in partners)
                    {
                        if (i != "")
                        {
                            tradePartners.AddLast(i);

                        }
                    }

                   countries.InsertItem(new Country(columns[0], Double.Parse(columns[1]),Double.Parse(columns[2]), Double.Parse(columns[3]) ,int.Parse(columns[4]),tradePartners));
                }

            }
```

Here is the code for my inorder traversal:

```
 public void InOrder()
    {
        inOrder(root);

    }

    private void inOrder(Node<T> tree)
    {
        if (tree != null)
        {
            inOrder(tree.Left);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tree.Data.ToString());

            inOrder(tree.Right);

        }
```

This code produces the following output for a few test countries:

Argentina 3  22.7 0.6 45 Brazil,Chile,

Australia 3.3  2.2 -5 2 China,Japan,New_Zealand,

Brazil 3  5.2 -2.2 84 Chile,Argentina,USA,

So I know that my classes are bieng stored correctly in the avl tree.

Comment: Did you just write this in a text editor?  You need a project with a form or window to display something on the screen.  Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: I have a project in visual studio with a form. On the form I have a listbox. My issue is I have no idea how to retrieve country name from the avl tree and display it in the listbox.

Comment: You have to give us more than that.  Do you have code where you build the tree?  Do you have an instance of the country class?  Did you try to get anything out of the tree at all?

Comment: I create instances of the country class and add them to the teee as I read lines from a csv file. I have amended my post to show what I am outputting from the avl tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are using as a data structure for your `countries` collection, but assuming its a List for now, you can do the following (NOTE: this sample is just to demonstrate displaying information on a UI for manipulation):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Country> countries = new List<Country>() { 
            new Country() { countryName = "Mattopia" , gdp = 1500, inflation = 1.5, f="hi"}, 
            new Country { countryName = "coffeebandit", gdp = 2000, inflation = 1.2, f="hey" }};
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "countryName";
        listBox1.DataSource = countries;
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string countryName { get; set; }
        public double gdp { get; set; }
        public double inflation { get; set; }
        public double tradeBalance { get; set; }
        public int hdiRanking { get; set; }
        public LinkedList<string> tradePartners { get; set; }
        public string f;
    }
```

Then, you can use the selected index changed event to populate your fields:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Country country = (Country)listBox1.SelectedValue;
        //fill up all other GUI controls
        textBox1.Text = country.f;
        textBox2.Text = country.inflation.ToString();
    }
```

And if you want to process text changes:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Country country = (Country)listBox1.SelectedValue;
        if (country != null)
        {
            country.f = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

This will give you the following display:

[image]

[image]

This should demonstrate the basics of how to edit a class in a WinForms UI.
For more advanced examples, I would recommend using other Events to capture information as your needs change.